# Including <atomic> breaks GCC's conversion-null diagnostic, and distcc fixes it. (Minimal examples included)

Tags: gcc, c++11, gcc-warning, distcc

This question actually consists of two observations.

**First: The inclusion of `<atomic>` makes GCC not emit the `conversion-null` diagnostic in at least some cases where it otherwise does.**
For example, consider the file `noerror.cpp`:

```
#include <atomic>
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wconversion-null"
int * foo() {return false;}
```

This file (`error.cpp`) is identical except for commenting out the include:

```
//#include <atomic>
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wconversion-null"
int * foo() {return false;}
```

If I attempt to compile `error.cpp`, I get an error as expected:

```
$ g++-4.8 -c -std=c++11 error.cpp
error.cpp: In function ‘int* foo()’:
error.cpp:3:21: error: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘int*’ [-Werror=conversion-null]
 int * foo() {return false;}
                     ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

I get the same results if I omit the `#pragma` and compile with `-Werror` instead. This is also expected: according to [the GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), the warning is enabled by default.

To my surprise, I can compile `noerror.cpp` with no errors. Even if the `<atomic>` header suppressed warnings and errors through `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignore`, the explicit pragma in my code should re-enable them, and yet it doesn't.

Incidentally, `clang++` errors as expected regardless of whether the header is included:

```
error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'bool'
```

**Second: Running with distcc restores proper behavior**
I have multiple workstations. If I attempt to build locally on any of them, I encounter the above behavior. If, however, distcc attempts to built it on any remote machine, the error is emitted properly. (This is how I discovered this issue in the first place; our build would with high probability make distcc fallback to local compilation). In fact, even if I have `distcc` SSH to my own machine, the proper behavior (i.e. an error) is restored:

```
$ DISTCC_HOSTS='localhost' distcc g++-4.8 -c -std=c++11 noerror.cpp # no error
$ DISTCC_HOSTS='@[my_ip_address]' distcc g++-4.8 -c -std=c++11 noerror.cpp
noerror.cpp: In function ‘int* foo()’:
noerror.cpp:3:21: error: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘int*’ [-Werror=conversion-null]
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

It is not clear to me how `distcc` manages to restore the proper behavior.

Version information: I'm running Ubuntu `3.5.0-46-generic`, GCC 4.8.1, and distcc 3.1.

## Summary

Including `<atomic>` seems to break GCC's `conversion-null` diagnostic. And somehow, using distcc fixes it. **I've searched but been unable to find any reference to a similar bug. Is this pilot error, a known issue, or should I file a GCC bug report?**

[Edit: The code snippets were from when I made it a warning instead of an error. Pasted the corrected version]

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html that `#pragma GCC diagnostic error` really doesn't look like a good idea

Comment: @user2485710 I ordinarily use command line flags. However, I wanted to address the possibility that the `<atomic>` header unset that diagnostic internally using pragmas and forgot to reset it (e.g. push but no pop). Can you elaborate as to why you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: irrelevant, the gcc documentation clearly says that that `#pragma` has an inconsistent behaviour. You can't say "it doesn't work" if that kind of approach it's not even supposed to work from the start. Just use command line options, always, this is not what you want.

Comment: @user2485710 The documentation states that some warning are controllable, and I've verified that the pragma works for that particular warning. Regardless, you're not being constructive: **I have the same behavior if I specify it at the command line, as I stated in the question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've further found that this only occurs when combining compilation and preprocessing in a single step. This accounts for the difference in behavior when using `distcc`: it preprocesses all the code on the local machine, and compiles it remotely.

Despite @user2485710's comments to the contrary, this is not a case of pilot error or using a poorly documented feature. This is a *bona fide* bug, and I've reported it as such:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60304

[As of now it's unresolved, but Harald van Dijk noted that GCC suppresses the warning because it (wrongly) thinks it's in a system header. The error/warning can be re-exposed by using `-Wsystem-headers`.]